# How do I get started creating Inventor Add-ins?

Tags: visual-studio, add-in, autodesk-inventor

I'm trying to figure out how to create some Autodesk Inventor 2016 add-ins for the templates I'm creating for my company. My background is minimal: I've been relatively successful in creating iLogic rules, but I couldn't tell you the difference between C+ and Visual Basic or any other languages.

I think I'm supposed to be coding in Visual Basic for this. I tried [this](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=17324828) "get started" guide, which had me download Visual Studio 2015 and Blend for Visual Studio 2015, but the guide is written for older versions of Visual Studio, and when I tried their code in my Inventor Templates, Inventor kept crashing.

I'm totally lost here. Any advice would be welcome!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with VBA (Tools > VBA editor). You can find sample code to try in the help (C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Inventor 2016\Local Help\admapi_20_0.chm)